# OpenCV Image Processing With Video

Tags: python, bots, ui-automation, browser-automation, game-automation

I'm working on a bot for a game and currently finding how I could get it to see the browser tab (on chromebook/linux rn btw). My idea is to feed it a livestream of the tab and have it interact using OpenCV but don't know if OpenCV can take video.

Is there anyway I could get OpenCV to look at the tab?

Comment: No. OpenCV can only handle video files or streams that come from hardware directly plugged into your computer, like a webcam. It cannot use a stream that comes from a browser tab as input.

Comment: so if i pluged in a hdmi cord and put the webcam next to the monitor that it was using the hdmi to show itself on it would work?

Comment: stop. don't. just get a library for screenshotting. mss or d3dshot or dxcam.